# Is 2 Chronicles 35:26-27 referring to 2 Kings, or to a different book?

Tags: 2-kings, 2-chronicles

2 Chronicles 35:26-27 (NIV):

> 26 The other events of Josiah’s reign and his acts of devotion in accordance with what is written in the Law of the Lord— 27 all the events, from beginning to end, are written in the book of the kings of Israel and Judah.

Is this the same Book of Kings that appears in our Bibles, or is it a different book?

Comment: You may be interested in the list of different sources employed by the Chronicler given in [Richard Pratt's commentary](http://www.thirdmill.org/newfiles/ric_pratt/OT.Pratt_Chronicles_Intro.pt.1.pdf), p. 5. The conclusions here are a bit too easy (e.g., many would disagree with "The Chronicler's use of these many sources indicates his strong desire to convey a true account of Israel's past", since references can also be used to make something doubtful *look* trustworthy), but the list of references can still be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The commentary to Chronicles ([here](http://mg.alhatorah.org/Full/Divrei_HaYamim_II/35.26#e1n7)) [ascribed (by some) to Rashi](https://www.magnes-press.com/Book/The+Commentary+on+Chronicles+Attributed+to+Rashi.aspx?name=The%20Commentary%20on%20Chronicles%20Attributed%20to%20Rashi&code=45-101113&docNo=1&qid=1&from=Authors/Eran%20Viezel.aspx) states that this is indeed the Book of Kings found in our Bibles (he specifically links it to [2 Kings 23:25](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=2%20Kings%2023%3A25&version=NIV)).

Comment: By citing only a Rashi this answer reveals lack of effort from the OP!

Comment: @Bach I cannot disagree.